# Mutablecopy mem leaking?

Tags: iphone

Does this line leak memory? Please explain if yes or no.

```
Person.h
-------
NSMutableString *address;


Person.m
--------
@synthesize address;

-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    address = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    return self;
}

-(void) funcA()
{
    [address appendFormat:@"located|at|%@", @"Singapore"];
     address = [[address stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"|" withString:@" "] mutableCopy];
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    [address release];
    [super release]
}
```

=address is a NSMutableString and it is also a property. I only release it on dealloc method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are leaking here:

```
[address appendFormat:@"located|at|%@", @"Singapore"];
address = [[address stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"|" withString:@" "] mutableCopy];
```

You are replacing the address with a new `NSMutableString` on the second line.

Just use [`replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000156-BCIFDIAF) so you don't have to replace the string.

```
[address appendFormat:@"located|at|%@", @"Singapore"];
[address replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"|" withString:@" " options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, address.length -1)];
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I think my post was incomplete. Please take a look again. I am not using ARC.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it again. But its not working. The "|" are not replaced by " " after the second line. Any thoughts?

Comment: I got a workaround:

    NSString *temp = [[address stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"|" withString:@" "];
    [address setString:temp];

this one works.. :D